# Why are not all results of my calculation being printed

Tags: python

i am wondering how i can print and see all the results of my calculation? At the moment i can only see 5 of the result. It should be possible to see all results right? But how? Using python 2.7. Thanks in advance for your help and fast responses.

```
in[]  print optv['x'].round(3)
out[] [ 0.123  0.122  0.    ...,  0.     0.     0.   ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! what is your calculation? Please post all of your code and post your desired outcome. That will help us, help you! :) Currently, this question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

NumPy automatically summarizes the printed representation of arrays with more than 1000 elements. To disable this, use [`numpy.set_printoptions`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html):

```
numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=numpy.inf)
```